# "hierarchical" view by default

Tags: eclipse

I develop an RCP based on CDT with my plugins.
I need at project creation, by default, in the view "Project Explorer", the "Project presentation" is in "hierarchical" rather than in "flat".
It's a workspace preferences, thoses I think:

```
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer.filterActivation=
\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot
\:org.eclipse.cdt.ui.navigator.filters.AnonymousStructFilter
\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.HideTopLevelProjectIfNested
\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.HideFolderWhenProjectIsShownAsNested
\:org.eclipse.cdt.ui.navigator.filters.ForwardDeclarationFilter
\:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.nestedProjectContentProvider\=true
```

How can I force this preferences  by default to all workspaces?

Comment: Default preference values can be specified in a `plugin_customization.ini` file as described in the Eclipse help

Answer (score 0):

I've added in the plugin_customization.ini:

```
# Project explorer default prefs
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer.activatedExtensions=org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui.makeTargets.content=true
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resourceContent=true
org.eclipse.cdt.ui.navigator.content=true
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets=true
org.eclipse.team.ui.patchSyncNavigatorContent=true
org.eclipse.team.ui.resourceContent=true
org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.nestedProjectContentProvider=true
org.eclipse.remote.ui.navigatorContent.connections=true


org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer.filterActivation=
```

:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.filters.startsWithDot:org.eclipse.cdt.ui.navigator.filters.AnonymousStructFilter:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.HideTopLevelProjectIfNested:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.nested.HideFolderWhenProjectIsShownAsNested:org.eclipse.cdt.ui.navigator.filters.ForwardDeclarationFilter